# Unable to display menu on right click react-big-calendar

Tags: material-ui, react-big-calendar

I am trying to display menu on right click with react-big-calendar and material ui,
the issue that menu isnt display correctly on html its going on top right corner,
My code is:

```
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
return (
    <>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={() => redirectToEvent(selectedEvent)}>
          <ImportContactsTwoToneIcon
            color="primary"
            style={{ marginLeft: "15px" }}
          />{" "}
          פתח אירוע
        </MenuItem>
      
      </Menu>
 <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={events}
        step={60}
        views={["month", "day"]}
        onSelectEvent={(event, e) => {
        
          redirectToEvent(event);
        }}
        components={
          {
            eventWrapper: ({ event, children }) => (
              <div
                onContextMenu={
                  e => { 
                    setSelectedEvent(event);
                  
                //think this is the issue
                   setAnchorEl(e);
                
                    e.preventDefault();
                  }
                }
              >
                {children}
              </div>
            )
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Material-UI has an example of providing a [Context Menu](https://mui.com/components/menus/#context-menu), and it doesn't seem to use an `anchorEl` prop, or take the bare 'event' target object, placing a different object in state.

```js
  const handleContextMenu = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setContextMenu(
      contextMenu === null
        ? {
            mouseX: event.clientX - 2,
            mouseY: event.clientY - 4,
          }
        : // repeated contextmenu when it is already open closes it with Chrome 84 on Ubuntu
          // Other native context menus might behave different.
          // With this behavior we prevent contextmenu from the backdrop to re-locale existing context menus.
          null,
    );
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setContextMenu(null);
  };
```

From that part of the example, it would seem you need to update your `onContextMenu` accordingly. Since you're setting multiple state values for your menu, both for it's positioning and the referenced `selectedEvent`, you may want to use a reducer for state instead.

Then, on the `<Menu>` itself, it also mutates that state.

```js
<Menu
  open={contextMenu !== null}
  onClose={handleClose}
  anchorReference="anchorPosition"
  anchorPosition={
    contextMenu !== null
    ? { top: contextMenu.mouseY, left: contextMenu.mouseX }
    : undefined
  }
>
// menu items
</Menu>
```

And, since you've placed the `<Menu>` inside of your `<Calendar>`'s container object, what sort of styling is on your container and could that effect it's layout as well? (I don't know if Material-UI automatically portals it's menu in this scenario or not)